# Git Bash config error running git config to edit global configuration

Tags: windows, git

When I run `git config --edit --global`, I get the error message below on git bash:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

It seems Git has by default picked Visual Studio 2017 as its core editor during installation.

Ideally this is supposed to open git configuration using the default editor picked during installation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error by running the below git command,

git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe'"